# null exception error datatable c#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am trying to create a matrix with the headers *rows* and *columns* for my rows and columns respectively. I get an error when I have two of the same value in *columns*. However, it works when I have two of the same value in *rows*. Why?

The error:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll
>   Additional information: 'Set property 'System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl.ItemsSource' threw an exception.' Line number '15' and line position '48'.

[image]

My xaml:

```
 <Window.Resources>
        <app:MatrixToDataViewConverter x:Key="MatrixToDataViewConverter"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid>
            <DataGrid.ItemsSource>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MatrixToDataViewConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="ColumnHeaders" ElementName="Result"/>
                    <Binding Path="RowHeaders" ElementName="Result"/>
                    <!--<Binding Path="Values"/>-->
                </MultiBinding>
        </DataGrid.ItemsSource>
      </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

My cs-code:

```
public partial class PopUp : Window
{  
    public string[] RowHeaders { get; set;  }

    public string[] ColumnHeaders { get; set;  }

    public ResultPopUp(Array[] Result, List<int> Vb1, List<int> Vb)
    {
        RowHeaders = new string[Vb.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < Vb.Count; i++)
        {
            RowHeaders[i] = Vb[i];
        }

        ColumnHeaders = new string[Vb1.Count];
        for (int j = 0; j < Vb1.Count; j++)
        {
            ColumnHeaders[j] = Vb[j];
        }
        try
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }                
    }    
}

public class MatrixToDataViewConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var myDataTable = new DataTable();

        string[] columns = values[0] as string[];
        string[] rows = values[1] as string[];
        myDataTable.Columns.Add("---"); //Upper left corner

        foreach (string value in columns)
        {
            myDataTable.Columns.Add(value); // this is where the error occurs when trying to add the second value if it is the same as the first one.
        }  

        foreach (string value in rows)
        {
            myDataTable.Rows.Add(value);
        }

        return myDataTable.DefaultView;
    }    

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your Convert() function call

Comment: There is no function call. The convert method is called when you initialize the component, I think @SurajS

Comment: Comment about adding same column name more than once to a DataTable causing an error

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean? I wrote that comment just so you guys could see where the error occurred. @user6144226

Comment: @Anna DataTable column names MUST be unique, this kind of consfuses me since the error shouldn't be a nulffReference, unless the nullReference happens somewhere else.

Comment: Post the StackTrace

Comment: Okay I understand! Then I guess the problem is that the DataTable column names are the same.. Thank you so much!! @user6144226

Comment: @user6144226 And it's not possible to show the StackTrace by pressing the arrow.

Answer (score 0):

I think that mistake is here:

```
public string[] RowHeaders { get; set;  }
public string[] ColumnHeaders { get; set;  }
```

If you do not create arrays in constructor of ResultPopUp, RowHeaders and ColumnHeaders will be null.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have columns with the same column names.

so change your code to

```
   myDataTable.Columns.Add();
   //Creates an unique column name thats not duplicated.

   myDataTable.Columns[myDataTable.Columns.Count-1][0] = value[0];
```

Thats create the column and put the values in the cell by addressing it.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried implementing this but I get the error 'Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Data.DataColumn'.

Comment: @Anna ,sorry missed the index of column value,see the update

Comment: No worries. Thank you for your time!